# Determine whether the given set is a vector space with the usual addition and scalar multiplication of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> $1$. The set of all continuous functions $f$ defined on the interval $[-1, 1] \ $such that $f(0)=1.$
>
> $2$. The set of all continuous functions $f$ defined on the real line $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty $.
>
> $3$. The set of all twice differentiable functions $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R} \ $such that $f''(x)+f(x)=0$.

At question $1$, first of all I use scalar $k$ and function $f,g ∈ [-1, 1].$

But I don't know what I do next... also how I use the condition $f(0)=1$?

At question $2$, I have no clue what I do first... and I don't know how I use the condition too..

At question $3$, I know that solution of $2$nd linear ODE : $y(x)=a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)$

So let $y(x)=a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)$ and $g(x)=c\cos(x)+d\sin(x)$

Then $y(x)+g(x)=(a+c)\cos(x)+(b+d)\sin(x)$.

Also, $ky(x)=ak\cos(x)+bk\sin(x)$

Thus It is closed in usual addition and scalar multiplication.

Is it right about question $3$?

Give me some hints for solving this problem alone..

Answer (score 1):

The set $S$ of functions satisfying 1 is NOT a vector space.

Let $f,g \in S$, is $f+g \in S$? Let's check $$(f+g)(0) = f(0)+g(0) = 1+1 = 2\neq 1.$$
$S$ is NOT a vector space.

The set $T$ of functions satisfying 2 IS a vector space.

Let $f,g \in T$ and $k \in \mathbb{R}$, are $f+g,kf \in T$? Let's check $$\lim_{x\to \infty}(f+g)(x)  =\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)+\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x) = 0+0 = 0.$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}(kf)(x)  =\lim_{x\to \infty}k(f(x)) = k\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)= 0.$$
The limit sum and multiplication steps are valid since both limits exist.

$S$ is a vector space.

Your reasoning for 3 is correct but you could use the properties of differentiation of sums and prove it without using the actual solution of the ODE.

Comment: Oh..I'm confused about above conditions... I think conditions must satisfy only function f(x)... Thank you so much :)

Comment: If you find the solution accurate and helpful would you mind accepting it as correct?Thank you.